# Best way to convert 8 boolean to one byte?

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, byte, bit

I want to save 8 boolean to one byte and then save it to a file(this work must be done for a very large data), I've used the following code but I'm not sure it is the best one(in terms of speed and space):

```
int bits[]={1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1};
char a='\0';
for (int i=0;i<8;i++){
  a=a<<1;
  a+=bits[i]
}
//and then save "a"
```

can anyone give me a better code(more speed) ?

Comment: That's as good as any.

Comment: Are you sure that works? You leftshift before writing the first bit.

Comment: The one thing you're failing to do is clear `a` before starting.

Comment: @Blob: Shifting first is the way to go here.

Comment: @Blob my code is running properly, and saves data correctly.

Comment: Yeah, you don't want to shift after, as that would bugger up the final result.  And trying to avoid the shift would require messier code.  It's correct as shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind using SSE intrinsics, then [_mm_movemask_epi8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s090c8fk%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is an excellent fit. It uses 16 bytes, but you can just set the others to zero.

For example (not tested)

```
__m128i values = _mm_loadl_epi64((__m128i*)array);
__m128i order = _mm_set_epi8(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
                             0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
values = _mm_shuffle_epi8(values, order);
int result = _mm_movemask_epi8(_mm_slli_epi32(values, 7));
```

This assumes the array is an array of chars. If you can't make that happen, it takes some more loads and packs and it becomes a bit annoying.

Comment: I tested this command and it seems that has a better performace but it returns wrong result. when I give it character array with bits 11001000   it returns me 19 which is not correct.

Comment: @abdolahS looks right to me, or did you want it reversed?

Comment: yes I want it in a reverse order! how can I do it. thanks for your answer.

Comment: thanks harold. it now gives me the correct answer. I can reverse the array but it is not optimized way. I'll use this one instead.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding

> **”** can anyone give me a better code(more speed)

you should **measure**. Most of the impact on the speed of serializing to file is i/o speed. What you do with the bits will likely have an *unmeasurably* small impact, but if it has any impact then that is likely mostly influenced by your original representation of the sequence of booleans.

---

Now regarding the given code

```
int bits[]={1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1};
char a='\0';
for (int i=0;i<8;i++){
a=a<<1;
a+=bits[i]
}
//and then save "a"
```

- Use `unsigned char` as byte type, just on principle.
- Use bitlevel OR, the `|` operator, again just on principle.
- Use prefix `++`, yes, also that just on principle.

The “on principle” for the first point is because in practice your code will not run on any machine with sign-and-magnitude or one's complement representation of signed integers, where `char` is signed. But I think it's generally a good idea to express in the code exactly what one intends doing, instead of rewriting it as something slightly different. And the intention here is to deal with bits, an unsigned byte.

The “on principle” for the bitlevel OR is because for this particular case there's no practical difference between bitlevel OR and addition. But in general it's a good idea to write in code what one means to express. And then it's no good to write a bitlevel OR as an addition: it might even trip you up, bite you in the a**, in some other context.

The “on principle” for the prefix `++` is because in practice the compiler will optimize prefix and postfix `++` for a basic type, when the expression result isn't used, to the very same machine code. But again it's generally better to write what one intends to express. Asking for an original value (the postfix `++`) is just misleading a reader of the code when you're not ever using that original value – and as with the bitlevel OR expressed as addition, the pure increment expressed as postfix `++` might trip you up, bite you in the a**, in some other context, e.g. with iterators.

---

The general approach of explicitly coding up shifting and ORing appears to me to be fine because `std::bitset` does not support initialization from a sequence of booleans (only initialization from a text string), so it doesn't save you any work. But generally it's a good idea to check the standard library, whether it supports whatever one wants to do. It might even happen that someone else chimes in here with some standard library based approach that I didn't think of! ;-)

Comment: Why not unsigned int "on principle"?

Comment: @NeilKirk: If you mean, why not `unsigned int` as a byte type, on most machines an `unsigned` is more than one byte. It *can* be one byte, depending on the platform. But usually it's more. And given the OP's task of storing byte values in a file, if he wants to do that efficiently then a good approach is to output a good chunk of bytes, a byte sequence, at a time. Then an exact byte type is needed for the sequence items.

Comment: Sorry I was referring to type of `bits` but I see now you were referring to type of `a`.

Answer (score -1):

Replace the `+=` operator by `|=`, which is the bit-wise operation (and actually what you want to do here). 
Use `unsigned char` for your truth values, if possible.

Unless you want to hand-unroll your loops and/or use SIMD intrinsics, that would be the most compiler-optimizable solution, I guess.

there's another trick: `struct`s can have bit offsets, and you can use `union` on them to misuse them as ints.

By the way: your code is buggy. You shift first, then write; you use addition, but a `signed char`, which will definitely go wrong for the 7th and 8th bits (given you erroneously shift too early; if you did that properly, only the 8th bit will cause hazard).

Comment: Since he's only adding a single 0/1 value, and the bit is known to be zero to start with (if the accumulator is cleared before starting) there's no effective difference between adding and ORing.

Comment: @HotLicks: yes there is -- he's using signed int, so shifting a 1 into the highest bit will invert the sign of his value; then, +1 isn't necessarily the same as |1.

Comment: So??  What would happen differently??

Comment: (I will agree that using OR would be clearer.  But functionally no different, in the above context.)

Comment: @HotLicks: I do agree that in above context it doesn't make a difference -- However, OP doesn't tell us about the "save it to a file" mechanism he's going to use. Maybe something later pads char to an 32 bit signed int -- in which case *all* the leading bits are 1.