# Convert an array of bools (8 byte bools) to an int or a char by using SSE intrinsics

Tags: c++, arrays, boolean, sse, bit

How can I convert an array of bools (8 byte bools) to an `int` or a `char` by using SSE intrinsics ?

Suppose I have this array:

```
bool array[8] = {1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0};
```

and I want to convert it to a char with bits `'11001000'`.

harold suggested me in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28382697/best-way-to-convert-8-boolean-to-one-byte) to do it with below commands but it does not work correctly:

```
__m128i values = _mm_loadl_epi64((__m128i*)array);
int result = _mm_movemask_epi8(_mm_slli_epi32(values, 7));
```

Comment: That looks like it should work OK - what result are you getting ?

Comment: @PaulR , when I run it gives me 19 which is not correct.

Comment: As @Tafuri says below, 19 is correct - you're just reading the bits in the wrong order. Either write out your array in the correct order or reverse the order of the bits in the result.

Comment: Note that @harold has now updated his answer on your original question to give you the reversed order you seem to need, so I'm closing this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

This code seems to be correct, and 19 is indeed the correct output. Keep in mind that the least significant bit in the generated result will be the first bool in the array not the last one.
If you reverse the order of the bools in the array you will get 200 as result instead.